# Hibernate optimize one-to-many collection loading from fully loaded entity sets

Tags: hibernate, optimization, collections, load, one-to-many

for most entity classes my Hibernate application usually loads **all** entity of the class. Is it possible to tell Hibernate that all the entities of some class are already loaded, so it wont make any db query anymore to fill one-to-many collections of that class?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible unless you store the OneToMany association and the target of the association in the second-level cache.

This of course has implications if these entities can be modified by another application, or if the application itself modifies these entities and is clustered across several JVMs.

Otherwise, using the second-level cache for such entities is a very good solution. And you could then even avoid to load all the entities in each session, since they would be (lazily) pre-loaded in the cache already.

Comment: Thank you Nizet, can you recommend me a tutorial on hibernate second-level cache?

Comment: No. I'd start with the reference documentation. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Thank you again Nizet. Will ask you more questions probably if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: Could you please tell me which second-level cache implementations are compatible with Hibernate 4?

Comment: No idea. I don't use Hibernate4 yet.